# Filter on empty related field - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join, nested-forms

Asking this questions as I did not find any topics which could help me solve my problem. 
Background: relatively new to Rails, building an order management system. To simplify, I have 3 models with which I am having an issue: Item, SupplierQuote and SupplierQuoteDetail

Item gives a name, description and part number to the Item

```
 class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :supplier_quote_details
   has_many :supplier_quotes, through: :supplier_quote_details
```

SupplierQuote gives a Quote reference and date to the quote

```
 class SupplierQuote < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :supplier_quote_details
    has_many :items, through: :supplier_quote_details
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :supplier_quote_details, 
    :reject_if => lambda {|x| x[:item_id].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
```

SupplierQuoteDetail gives a price to the Item, based on a specific quote

```
 class SupplierQuoteDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :item
    belongs_to :supplier_quote
```

When I input new Quotes, I have a nested form (with field for), and in the nested field_for I have a select tag that allows me to select an item for which I can input a price. However in my select dropdown I want only the values where I have no previous price input. So in my supplier_quotes_controller, I have:

```
@items = Item.joins(:supplier_quote_details).merge(SupplierQuoteDetail.where(unit_price: nil))
```

But this gives me an empty dropdown! (it should not as I have many items with no price):

```
 <%= f.fields_for :supplier_quote_details, :wrapper => false do |it| %>
   <tr class="fields">
     <td><%= it.select(:item_id, @items.map {|item| [[item.description, item.PN, item.SN].join("   |   "), item.id]}) %></td>
```

Please help! How do I filter correctly in this related field? The above is the only method I found up to now.

Thank you so much!

A.

Comment: try to debug it with the output query of this call `@items = Item.joins(:supplier_quote_details).merge(SupplierQuoteDetail.where(unit_price: nil))`. What query this is forming?

Comment: try `Item.includes(:supplier_quote_details).where( :supplier_quote_details => { :unit_price => nil } )`

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: please mark answer correct and close it..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
 Item.includes(:supplier_quote_details).where( :supplier_quote_details => { :unit_price => nil }
```